How to manage a repo with other repos on it?
I'm using BitBucket and have a repo (A) that has a copy of two other repos (B+C).
Every time that I make a change on repo B or C, I have to remember to copy that changes to the repo A and push that changes in order to have the repo A always updated.
Is there a way to avoid this manual operations and have the repo A with the latest changes on to repo B and C?
I need to be able to work separately on repos B and C.
I tried to use submodules and set repo B and C as submodules of repo A, however I found that submodules need to be updated manually in order to point to the last commit of each repo.
Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

"I found that submodules need to be updated manually" But the update process is simpler for submodules than manually copy changes. So IMO submodules is the way to go. Or [tag:git-subtree].

Thank you for your comment. I have to agree with you, it is way simpler than the old method.
I'll stick with submodules but I'll keep looking for an automatic process to update the repo-A.

As you probably already encountered, submodules is the solution to you problem. And yes, you have to update them manually to point to the latest commit, but that is kind of the point of it.
Alternatively, if you use CMake, (Which I suggest you should, but that's just my 2 cents), you could use FetchContent. It works similarly to submodules but on a build system level. It has a few more configuration options and pulls a remote repository, pointing to a specific branch or tag.

Thank you for the suggestion, I'm not familiar with CMake but I'll definitely look into to it.
A workaround, at least for now, is a pipeline on repo-A that runs at the end of each day and updates the submodules.
